# Hugo on GitLab Pages

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, hugo

I am trying to deploy a Hugo website with GitLab Pages.
I followed the [Hugo tutorial](https://gohugobrasil.netlify.app/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-gitlab/).
My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is the following:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo:latest

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

pages:
  script:
  - hugo
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

However, impossible for me to correctly deploy the website.
I always have the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.0~beta.115.g598a7c91 (598a7c91)
  on blue-2.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default XxUrkriX, system ID: s_90897a2659b5
  feature flags: FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:08
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo:latest ...
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo:latest ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": error pulling image configuration: unknown blob (manager.go:237:0s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo:latest" with specified policies [always]: error pulling image configuration: unknown blob (manager.go:237:0s)
```

Any idea of the issue ?
Thanks!